# Strange Google OAuth2 problem, .Net 4.8 Webform. Sometimes page stops loading AFTER OAuth2 authentication

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, webforms

I have an internal business app with Google OAuth set up, running on a Windows Server 2019 VM. Using .Net 4.8, NuGet packages all updated, 2019 all updated.

Login works fine MOST of the time, but sometimes, AFTER authentication, it will stop loading/processing the sitemaster and just dump onto the screen either the favicon (the image, by itself, in the center of the screen, and stop), or the contents of one of the CSS files, dumped onto the screen, and stop. The CSS/favicon are at the beginning of the sitemaster page.

When this happens, I can go back to the login page, click the button again and it works just fine.

Anyone run into this before?

I also have a 'standard' login option on the same login screen (username/password check against Active Directory) and that works 100% of the time. FWIW.